# Android Spinner out of memory on select

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I want to use a Spinner inside my Dialog. The Spinner appears and contains the data i want to show. But as soon as i select one of the items, memory usage shoots up and i end up getting an out of memory Exception. In logcat the first entry after selectin the item is D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM. I have no stacktraces whatsoever. Only some info output from the gc and two warnings about throwing an OOM.

```
class SearchTypeSpinner(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null): LinearLayout(context, attributeSet), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

private val types: List<String>
private val mapping: MutableMap<String, Int>
private val spinner: Spinner

init {
    types = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.filter_types).asList()
    spinner = Spinner(context)
    spinner.adapter = Adapter()
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = this
    spinner.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(context, attributeSet)
    addView(spinner)
}

override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {}

override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}

private inner class Adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = TextView(context)
        view.layoutParams = LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
        view.text = getTypeNameAtPosition(position)
        return view
    }

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return types.size
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know if i can provide additional information and thanks in advance.

Comment: How much memory you have assigned in Gradle.property?

Comment: I don't think that's relevant. For the build i have 1536M. But oom is not on my build machine but on the mobile device at around 250M.

Comment: What kind of "data" do you want to show? I don't think the issue is related to your `Spinner`, but to the data that you should display after

Comment: In the spinner i just show three strings from the array in the resources. And those strings are definitely below 20 chars so should not be the problem. Since i don't display anything else in the dialog yet and even the listener to the spinner doesn't do anything, i'm pretty sure the problem is related to my configuration of the spinner.

Comment: Are you using this spinner in xml or code?

Comment: I tried both, same problem with code and xml